# Drupal node "ranking" based on views sorting

Tags: views, commerce, rules, 7

I am creating a site where there are nodes (which are "causes") that users can donate to (i.e. buying a donation product using [Drupal Commerce](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce), which is sort of irrelevant, but just for the record).

I would like to display a "ranking" on each node based on how much money has been donated to that cause. It will be output something like "Rank: 50 out of 210".

My question is: *What is the best way to do this?*

I know how I could create a view and sort it by the criteria that I'm wanting, but then how to display on a node the index from the view... ? I don't know how to do that.

I've thought about figuring out a way to use Rules to assign a value to a field in the node whenever a donation is made... ? That might be a decent bet.

If anyone has any direction for me on this, I'd really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

No need to make things that difficult; Views supports a field that display the sort index. It's labeled ***Global: View result counter***.

[image: Views Counter]

It won't get you total results, but you can put that information in the header/footer with the ***Global: Result summary*** field.

[image: Views Result Summary]

Comment: thank you for your response. I'm afraid that's not quite what I'm looking for. See, on the node page is where I need to display the result and what needs to be displayed is just the "RANK out of TOTAL" text. So, whatever the view (or whatever) outputs, I need to be able to use a contextual filter to show exactly one result with the rank and total numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Ranking gave me some headaches too (user ranking). What I ended up doing was:

1) creating a Views VBO list (shows the ranking in the order I need),
2) sent it to Rules and load the list (load a list of entity ids from VBO action) 
3) and loop through it. Within the loop I added an INT counter variable. This variable sets the value of the ranking field on the user profile. The counter is increased by 1 at the end of the loop.

The rule is executed on cron (so the changes in the ranking are only then visible). I just could not figure out a better way but it works for me.